# How to satisfy unique constraint in django unit test without hardcoding?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, unique-constraint, model-mommy

I have set a unique constraint on email field of my Member model. Now while writing unit tests, my tests fail due to expiring unique constraint.

```py
def setUp(self):
    self.car_provider = mommy.make(Member, username="car_provider")
    self.car_provider.set_password("12345678")
    self.car_provider.save()

    self.applicant = mommy.make(Member, username="applicant")
    self.applicant.set_password("12345678")
    self.applicant.save()
```

I get following error:
"django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "account_member_email_a727987b_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=() already exists."

Comment: If your test is failing due to existing state from a previous run, it's *not* a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up `email` as a unique field you actually must have a test for that case and handle that exception somehow.

But to make this test run you should either provide an explicit value for `email` field in every `mommy.make()` call. Or you can populate it with randomly generated values with `_fill_optional` option.

Like:

```
self.car_provider = mommy.make(Member, username="car_provider", _fill_optional=['email'])
```

Comment: Sorry , just funny, if we have mommy.make() what of daddy.make(),.....          Really get me there :()